# Adding a Navigation link between site collections SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Morning all,

I want to add a hyperlink\navigation element from one site collection (site 1) to another site collection (site 2). 
I only want the link viable on site 1 to people who are permissioned in site 2.

If you do not have permission to view site 2 then the link in site one should not be visible .

Help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check the audience setting for navigation.

[image]

Official guideline below.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293